# Why does CLion not allow me to have nested ternary operators?

Tags: c++, nested, c++14, ternary-operator, clion

I am trying to have nested ternary expressions in C++14. My code is the following:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 5;
    string result = i % 2 == 0 ? "a" : i % 3 == 0 ? "b" : "c";

    return 0;
}
```

I am using CLion. I get an error on the last nexted expression `i % 3 == 0 ? "b" : "c"` saying `Type 'const char[2]' and 'const char[2]' are not compatible`. What am I doing wrong?

If it helps, here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(TestCLion)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES relop.cpp)
add_executable(TestCLion ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: FWIW the posted code compiled without error for me (after changing the #include line to #include <string> ) under clang/LLVM 9.0.0 on MacOS/X.  So you might be seeing a bug in your particular compiler

Comment: Please make a MINIMAL example.

Comment: @KerrekSB Updated

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yeah, perhaps its just CLion

Comment: @Victor2748 updated version compiles without errors for me as well (via g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp)

Comment: Code looks OK to me. I'd file a compiler bug report.

Comment: Maybe try grouping with parenthesis?

string result = i % 2 == 0 ? "a" : (i % 3 == 0 ? "b" : (i % 5 == 0 ? "c" : (i % 7 == 0 ? "d" : "e")));

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thank you. It compiles your way, but CLion still gives me an error.

Comment: @Marker Still highlights an error.

Comment: If this is the IDE, not the compiler, then it might help to give it a little hint that it's all about pointers. E.g. replace `"a"` with `&*"a"`, or just introduce a dummy `char const*`. No guarantee, but worth a try.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It worked! Thank you!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I introduced the pointers and the error is gone now

Comment: You shouldn't be including `<bits/stdc++.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug in CLion](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-11488).

The code will compile without errors. (using CLion 2017.3.1, GCC 6.3.0)